# JavaScript Form onkeyup Validation Errors

Tags: javascript, html

Not getting any errors in Aptana, so something I'm doing probably doesn't make sense. Basically, I am getting the value from a form and checking it against a regex. If the new checked variable isn't empty then I output to a different div that it is valid, and that it is not valid if the variable is empty.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var age_regex=/(1[8-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-5])/;
        var error_box= document.getElementById('error_box');
            function checkAge(x){
                var age = document.getElementById(x).value;
                var checked_age = test.age_regex(age);
                if (checked_age.value != "")
                error_box.innerHTML = "Correct!";
                else {
                error_box.innerHTML = "Incorrect!";
                }
                }
    </script>
```

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: Whats the problem with it? O.o

Comment: You'll have to explain what the problem is first... are you getting any errors elsewhere, what happens, etc?  Perhaps construct a demo.  See this: http://sscce.org

Comment: Problem is all you are doing is describing what the code is doing and that you have no error in Aptana. So one can wonder what is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I thought there would be some big obvious error. Nothing is happening.

Comment: Then put up a demo someplace so we have something to troubleshoot.

Comment: isnt `checked_age` a boolean and not an object with the property value? hence `if (checked_age.value != "")` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Why regex for age ? How about this :

```
function checkAge(str) {
    if(parseInt(str, 10) != str) {
        return false;
    }
    if(parseInt(str, 10) < 18 || parseInt(str, 10) > 35)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```